# How to async publish multiple messages?

Tags: python, asynchronous, rabbitmq, pika

I'm stuck with pretty simple example with using async Rabbitmq publishing (Pika) via python. Problem is: I'm trying to test speed of processing like 5000 log files via queue, publisher and worker and can't wrap my head about simple things.

For example, I declare async publisher, it has `_connection` property which is `pika async connection`. This async connection has ioloop going and whenever I run `publish` method, ioloop emits signal to run callback, to put message on queue, right?

And from practical part:
I took example of async publisher from 
http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/examples/asynchronous_publisher_example.html but when I tried to feed ioloop with my custom messages, publisher won't send them.

Code:
https://notebin.cc/1ptsu8p8tfk

Comment: Can you please provide an indented version of it? It quite unreadable now

Comment: Sure. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/c5zdvzDy) I took basic publisher from Pika docs and result of publishing 100k messages to queue was like 30-40 secs with acknowledge turned off.